# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range

Tags: c#-4.0

```
  public static void get_sum_while (int[] num,int len)
  {
    int sum2,i=0;
    while ( i<len)
    {
      sum2=sum2+num[i];
      i++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The sum of the series by while loop is {0}",sum2);
  }
  public static int get_sum_recur (int[] num,int len)
  {
    int sum3;
    if (len==0)
    return sum3=sum3+num[0];
    else
    {
      return sum3=num[len]+get_sum_recur(num,length-1);
    }

  }
}
```

Hello this gives sum of the series from three function the first two are okay but recursive did not give it give exception i don't where i go wrong and is it correct way to get sum by recursion?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of summing a list by recursion is to sum the an element of the list with the sum of the same list without the chosen element.

```
sum([a,b,c,d,e]) = a + sum([b,c,d,e])
```

So the initial value of the result have to be set to 0.
Then choose an element, for example the first one, add it to the current result and call sum on the rest of the list with the new result.
When list is empty, end recursion.

In pseudo code, because I don't have a C# compiler, this gives :

```
public static int get_sum_recur(int result, int[] list) {
  if (len(list)==0) {
    return result; // end recursion
  }
  else {
    return get_sum_recur(result+list[0], list[1:]);
  }

}

public static main {
  print(get_sum_recur(0, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
}
```